# how to only insert a script for browsers above IE 9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, scripting

I want to only inject a script onto my page if the browser is higher than IE 9. I.e. not IE 9 and below

I found this for including the script on IE 9 and below only:

```
if (/MSIE \d/.test(window.navigator.userAgent)) {
   // script goes here
}
```

but when I tried to negate it like so (not the exclamation mark):

```
if (!/MSIE \d/.test(window.navigator.userAgent)) {
   // script goes here
}
```

it didn't work

has anyone got a solution that would work?

basically I'm happy for the script to load in IE10, 11, edge, chrome, firefox etc

thanks

Comment: You might want to try [conditional comments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_comment) instead.

Comment: @str that wont work coz they are only supported up to IE9 so if I say in chrome `[! if IE9]` i.e. if not IE 9 then chrome wont parse it coz it does not recognise it

Comment: There is no need for other browsers to support it, see [Downlevel-revelead conditional comment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_comment#Downlevel-revealed_conditional_comment).

Comment: yes coz I want the scripts to load in anything BUT IE so chrome will see it, ignore it, and not load the script

Comment: "I want the scripts to load in anything BUT IE" is the opposite of "chrome will see it, ignore it, and not load the script". You *can* use Conditional Comments to do what you describe in the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!--[if gt IE 9]>
  <script...>
<![endif]-->
```

Try this conditional comment.

Answer (score 0):

See [Conditional Comments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_comment) and more specifically [Downlevel-revealed conditional comment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_comment#Downlevel-revealed_conditional_comment).

> [...] if writing code meant to display on non-IE browsers and on some
>   versions of IE), IE will then display the "`-->`" present before the
>   HTML content. This problem is easily solved by prepending "`<!`" to the
>   initial "`-->`" as follows:
>
> ```
> <!--[if gt IE 6]><!-->
> This code displays on non-IE browsers and on IE 7 or higher.
> <!--<![endif]-->
> ```
>
> The extra "`<!`" is ignored by non-IE browsers; it is also ignored by IE
>   regardless of the condition because if false, everything within the
>   conditional comment is ignored, and if true, the resulting tag `<!-->`
>   is unrecognized and therefore ignored.

To conditionally load a script in all non-IE browsers and on IE9 and higher, you can use this conditional comment:

```
 <!--[if gt IE 9]><!-->
 This code displays on non-IE browsers and on IE 9 or higher.
 <!--<![endif]-->
```